# openstack octavia failed to build compute instance

Tags: networking, openstack

I installed and configured octavia for openstack load balancing. but when i want create a new loadbalancer using `openstack loadbalancer create --name lb1 --vip-subnet-id subnet-pub` octavia worker log say: `ERROR octavia.controller.worker.v1.controller_worker octavia.common.exceptions.ComputeBuildException: Failed to build compute instance due to: Failed to retrieve image with amphora tag.`
why? (I use ubuntu)

another question is: I installed octavia on controller node. must install anything on compute node(s)?

Comment: It would seem you have no image tagged with "amphora" and belonging to the correct project (usually *service*). You can tag an image and change its project with [openstack image set](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/cli/command-objects/image.html#image-set).  No need for loadbalancing software on compute nodes.

Comment: thnx @berndbausch ... but i have an image tagged amphora! and it use my main project!

Comment: My guess is that your main project is not Octavia's project. Usually, Octavia uses the *service* project I think.

Comment: yes i used that! service project is my main project!

Comment: Check the Glance and/or Octavia logs to see which query is made to find the Amphora image. You may have to enable debug logging. Compare the query with the image properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and adding `--project service` solved it when uploading the image.

```bash
$ openstack image create amphora-x64-haproxy.qcow2 --container-format bare --disk-format qcow2 --private --tag amphora --file amphora-x64-haproxy.qcow2 --property hw_architecture='x86_64' --property hw_rng_model=virtio --project service
```

About the second question no need for anything to be installed on compute nodes. Only network access to `lb-mgmt-net` from controllers.

This [Link](https://storyboard.openstack.org/#!/story/2009103#comment-177969) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Set tag of image with value "amphora"

```
openstack image set --tag "amphora" image_name
```